# How do I remove the application title from global application menu?

Tags: unity, panel, appmenu

I've disabled the global application menu by removing 'indicator-appmenu' via apt. Unfortunately, the window title still appears on the panel bar whenever I mouse over the application.

Does anyone know if there's another indicator applet which can be removed to disable this effect?

Comment: Have you logged out after removing indicator-appmenu?

Comment: Yes, logged out, rebooted, sighuped, etc

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Disable the AppMenu ... for all applications" part.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html

There is one other step, and more packages removed.

Comment: Thanks for the info but these steps only remove the app menu, which I've already done. What remains is the application title, which stubbornly remains in the unity bar.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but wanted to keep the menu and just get rid of the title. Here is what worked for me (the only downside is that the title for regular windows will ni loger be bold)

1. Open the Configuration Editor (I'm not sure if it comes included out    of the box. You might have to install it first)
2. Go to    apps>metacity>general
3. Change titlebar_font to 0 (this will get rid of    all titles)
4. Check the box titlebar_uses_system_font (this will bring    back the titles for regular windows, but the titles will no longer be    bold)