# How can I prevent window title from appearing in the top panel?

Tags: unity, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the application title from global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74483/how-do-i-remove-the-application-title-from-global-application-menu)

I want to keep the global menu (actually prefer it) I've disabled auto-hide and the menu is always there, but when the window is not maximized, a chunk of the title is visible in the corner. I know it's a small matter, but I find it very annoying.
Is there any way to remove the window title from the panel? Any help appreciated

Comment: I've gone through the above and it's not a duplicate - I don't want to remove or disable the menu items (file, edit, view, etc.) only the window title